# How to check for Redis Cache connection status from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

I have been working on setting up a cache server for my nodejs application.
Below is my project I am working on. Simple one.

I have an external API that gives me a JSON response for a GET request.
I want to store those key and JSON (value) in a redis cache server. And I am able to do that.

Now when the GET request is called it comes to my node URL --> External API <-- JSON as response (which is stored in the cache).

For next request if the same GET comes, it goes to cache to fetch the key/value pair.

But here, if my cache server is not reachable or available, I have to go to API again to fetch the value.

I tried the code like below and it is failing when the Cache server is shutdown. How do I do a if-loop for getting the connection status of the redis cache server?

Below is my controller.js

```
function getRedisCacheConnection(){
    
        const REDIS_PORT = process.env.PORT || 6379;
        const client = redis.createClient(REDIS_PORT);
    
        client.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('Redis client connected');
            console.log(`${client.connected}`);
        });
    
        client.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('Something went wrong ' + err);
        })
    
       return client;
}

exports.getCityCode = (req,res)=>{
    var originCity = req.query.origincity;
    var originState = req.query.originstate;

    function setReponse(originCity, response){

        return response;
    }

    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        uri: `http://webapi.external.com/api/v3/locations?name=${originCity}`,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }

    request(options).then(function (response){
    res.status(200).send(setReponse(originCity, response));
    const client1 = getRedisCacheConnection();
    console.dir("setting key to Cache " + originCity);
    client1.setex(originCity, 3600, response);
    });
    
  
}

exports.Cache = (req,res,next) => {    

    const originCity = req.query.origincity;

    function setReponse(originCity, response){

        return response;
    }
        const client1 = getRedisCacheConnection();
        client1.get(originCity, (err,data) =>{
            if(err) throw err;
     
            if(data !== null){
                console.dir(originCity + " Getting Key from Cache");
                res.status(200).send(setReponse(originCity,data));
            }
            else{
                next();
            }
        });
  
       
}
```

Here is my router.js

```
app.get('/citycode/', city.Cache, city.getCityCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are throwing an error:

```
if(err) throw err;
```

Log the error and don't create an exception.

Comment: No it is still looking for cache connection. Not going to the API to fetch.

Comment: the official way is to use ping method

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createClient } from 'redis';
const client = redis.createClient();
// within the event handlers for error and connect you could use fs module to
// write to a file the state values 'connected' & 'disconnected' then reread them
// and perform a control block statement
    client.on('error', () => {
      logtoFile('disconnected');
          });
    client.on('connect', () => {
      logtoFile('connected');
    });
```